# Can i use all SQL command in android studio for database..?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

if i want to show the id and name info from the "Customers" Table,whose name and id is "David" and 2,for this query in SQL Command is like this,

```
SELECT id,name
FROM Customers
WHERE id=2 AND City='David';
```

For the same query if i write in android SQLite then it i'll,

```
rawQuery("SELECT id, name FROM Customers WHERE name = ? AND id = ?", new String[] {"David", "2"});
```

**Both (SQL and SQLite) commend are different.**

I want to know,can i use as same as SQL commend in android studio...?

Is it possible..?
if **yes**...how..?

Comment: "is it possible..?" -- yes. "if yes...how..?" -- `rawQuery("SELECT id,name FROM Customers WHERE id=2 AND City='David'", null);`. Note, though, that this is only a good idea if you are actually going to be hard-coding these parameters. If you wish to have variable data (sometimes `id` is `2` and sometimes it is `3`), please use the `?` placeholders approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write the code like this:

```
rawQuery("SELECT id, name FROM Customers WHERE name = 'David' AND id = '2'", null);
```

but it is not safe (there is always the risk of [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and it is not recommended.
Always use `?` placeholders to pass parameters to your query.